# Add custom tag to autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using autocomplete in jQuery as below :

```
$("#myDiv").autocomplete({
}
```

This is the standard jQuery auto complete functionality :http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Can the generated li tag be modified to include an extra tag ?

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Erlang</a></li>
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Erlang</a>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Erlang</a></li>
```

becomes (added tester) :

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" mytag="tester" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Erlang</a></li>
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Erlang</a>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Erlang</a></li>
```

Comment: At which point are you looking to add the `mytag` attribute? Also, you should note that if you're looking to make your HTML valid, the property should be called `data-mytag`, and you cannot place an `a` element between `li`.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan the 'mytag' attribute should be added when the page is loaded "you cannot place an a element between li" the jQuery autocomplete function does then, so it seems it an e element can be placed an li ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the focus callback function. Something like this...

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete li").attr("mytag", "tester");
    }
  });
});​
```

Check this - http://jsfiddle.net/gtND8/

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, then you could use **_renderItem** for doing that, like:

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item) {        
   return $( "<li></li>" )
      .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
      .append( "<a>"+ item.label + "</a>" )
      .after( "<a>"+ item.label + "</a>" ).addClass("ui-corner-all")
      .attr("tabindex", -1)
  .appendTo( ul );
}
```

Shows html as:

```
<li class="ui-corner-all ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Erlang</a>
</li>
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Erlang</a>
<li class="ui-corner-all ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><strong>Erlang</strong></a>
</li>
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><strong>Erlang</strong></a>
```

Did you mean something like this..